# Prevent gradient background from shrinking with window resize

Tags: html, css

Alright so, anyone help me out here if you can. I'm doing a gradient background with a size of 600% , because I'm using keyframes to have the gradient background transition to a new gradient once a button is pressed. How do I prevent the background gradient from shrinking together with the window when it is resized?

```css
.content {
                background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(188,222,242,1) 0%, rgba(215,164,241,1) 43%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 65%, rgb(1, 85, 255) 75%, rgb(164, 217, 255) 100%);
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(188,222,242,1) 0%, rgba(215,164,241,1) 43%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 65%, rgb(1, 85, 255) 75%, rgb(164, 217, 255) 100%);
                background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(188,222,242,1) 0%, rgba(215,164,241,1) 43%, rgb(255, 0, 0) 65%, rgb(1, 85, 255) 75%, rgb(164, 217, 255) 100%);
                filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#bcdef2",endColorstr="#dfc9ef",GradientType=2);
                background-size: 600% 600%;
            }

            @keyframes gradient { 100% {background-position: 100% 50%;} }
            @keyframes gradientback { 0% {background-position: 100% 50%;} 100% {background-position: 0% 0%;} }
```

I've tried using background-cover, but since gradients don't widely support transitioning, I'm using keyframes to change the 600% sized background's position in order to appear it to be transitioning, which works just fine. Changing the bg size to 'cover' kills that functionality.

Comment: You should probably just use a layered approach, with `:before`, an `:after` and a transition of opacity on both? This seems like a complicated solution that is really hard to reason about, let alone explain to someone else... Also, recently I read there a feature coming to allow transitions of parts of gradients - it was in the latest releade notes of Safari TP, but I forgot what it was called...